# ¿Cómo actualizar una imagen con JQuery si el nombre del archivo es el mismo?

Tags: jquery, html

En mi proyecto, las personas pueden incluir una fotografía personal para que se les pueda identificar fácilmente.

Lo que estoy haciendo en este momento es lo siguiente:

1. Monitorear el `input` con tipo `file` que tengo para que, al momento de que cambie de valor, se ejecute la acción de guardar dicha fotografia.
2. Utilizo la función `$.ajax()` para mandar el archivo al servidor y que de alli se procese.
3. El servidor devuelve el `path` en donde se almaceno la fotografía para que pueda reemplazar el valor de mi `img` en donde se debe mostrar.

Ahora con un poco mas de detalle:

Todo en el numeral 1 y 2 funciona bien. Despues, para el numeral 3, tengo lo siguiente. En mi archivo de php muevo el archivo y doy una respuesta con el siguiente código (simplificado por razones obvias):

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['usuariofoto']['tmp_name'],$directorio.$nombre_img);
$full_path = $directorio.$nombre_img;
$response = array(1,$full_path);
echo json_encode($response);
```

Entiendo que, si no se especifica lo contrario, `move_uploaded_file` sobreescribe el archivo, lo cual es bueno, ya que no quiero tener un monton de fotos para la misma persona. (`$nombre_img` es un id único para cada persona y `$directorio` es el nombre de la carpeta)

De regreso en JQuery, estoy intentando actualizar el img con

```
var response = JSON.parse(postresult);    
$("#usuariovistafoto").attr("src", response[1]);
```

Hasta aqui todo bien, pero la imagen no cambia. Al inspeccionar el elemento `img`, veo que tiene el mismo nombre que siempre, pero esto es normal, ya que estoy sobreescribiendo la fotografía. Refresco la página manualmente y, efectivamente, si se ha guardado la fotografía correctamente, ya que se despliega la nueva foto que he cargado.

Entonces, aqui esta el problema. Supongo que como el archivo tiene el mismo nombre, la imagen no se actualiza y se sigue viendo la misma fotografía, aunque, en efecto, todos los cambios si se han llevado a cabo.

¿Que tengo que hacer para que, por asi decirlo, mi `img` se vuelva a "renderizar" aunque tenga el mismo nombre de archivo en el `src`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso pasa porque la imagen estará en el cache.

Podrías añadirle un `?ver=1234` al final, ejemplo:

```js
$(function(){
    
    let timestamp = Math.floor( Date.now() );
    console.log('Antes del ajax: ' + $('img').attr('src') );
    
    // Ajax
    setTimeout(function(){
        
        $('img').attr('src', 'https://placeimg.com/640/480?ver=' + timestamp);
        console.log('Después del ajax: ' + $('img').attr('src') );
    }, 2500);   
});
```

```html
<img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

Así evitas que la imagen con el mismo nombre sea cacheada en el momento de recibirlo.

Comment: En este ejemplo si o si cambia la imagen... pero es solo una demostración

Comment: @Kenny - Correcto...  así evitas que el navegador cargue desde el cache

Comment: (Perdon por borrar el comentario) Pero esto tendría que hacerlo con Php, correcto? Por que mi src se ve algo asi: "fotos/12345.jpg" que es el path de mi foto y tambien lo que esta almacenado en la BD.

Comment: Si simplemente le agrego algo del lado del cliente, ya no va a hacer referencia a la foto que tengo en el servidor.

Comment: @Kenny - Si hace referencia.. pero el parámetro añadido es solo para distinguir la version del la imagen... es decir.. engañamos al navegador que se hace creer que es una nueva imagen... eso lo puedes hacer en el lado del servidor o del cliente...

Comment: Que curioso, intente solo añadirle el `timestamp` y no funciono. Cuando intente usar `"?ver=" + timestamp` si funciono. No lo hubiera imaginado. Muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda.. Saludos.

Comment: @Kenny - Seguro que te haz olvidado el `?` ... ;)

Comment: Si por eso te mencionaba, no habia incluido el `?ver=`. Pero ya esta solucionado. De nuevo gracias. :D

Comment: @Kenny - Solo para quitarte la duda... Intenta solo con el `?` y te funcionará también... ósea de esta manera: `$('img').attr('src', tuimagen.jpg?' + timestamp);` puedes escribir lo que quieras detras del `?` mientras sea diferente... saludos

Answer (score 0):

Este ejemplo con ajax, la función cargarImagenesAll() genera las filas de una tabla con las imagenes necesarias y despues de llamar a la funcion editarImagen() solo llamo nuevamente a cargarImagenesAll() para renderizar las imagenes,cabe mencionar que las imagenes las tengo en un campo longblob en la bd, espero les sirva.

```js
var cargarImagenesAll = function () {
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   data: array,
   url: 'assets/php/functions.php',
   success: function (data) {
   var res = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
   var mae,id_imagen;
   var filas = "";

   if (res.length > 0) {
    $("#imgconttabla").empty();
    var timestamp;
     
    for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
     mae = res[i];
                          id_imagen = mae.id_imagen;
     timestamp = (Math.floor( Date.now() )+i);

                          //en caso de que sea una imagen desde un directorio o url
                          //<img src='img/imagen1.jpg?ver=" + "+timestamp+"'/>
     filas = filas + "<tr id='" + id_imagen + "'><td><img src='assets/php/imagen.php?id=" + id_imagen + "&ver="+timestamp+"'/></td></tr>";
    }
    $("#imgconttabla").append(filas);

    }else{ ...(codigo aqui) }
   },error: function (e) { }
  });
};
```